# Why does this C++ code print out variables when it is not supposed to?

Tags: c++

I have a very simple C++ code that asks for two integer inputs in a loop and prints them in every iteration until the user inputs the character '|'. The code is as follows:

```
int main() {                                                                    
    int in_int1;                                                                
    int in_int2;                                                                

    cout << endl << "Enter numbers one at a time. Enter '|' to end.";           
    cout << endl << ">> ";                                                      
    while (cin >> in_int1 && in_int1 != '|') {                                  

        cout << ">> ";                                                          
        cin >> in_int2;                                                         

        if (in_int2 != '|') {                                                   
             cout << "int 1: " << in_int1 << endl;                              
             cout << "int 2: " << in_int2 << endl;                              
             cout << endl << ">> ";                                             
        } else break;                                                           
    }                                                                           

    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Here's a sample run which went exactly as expected:

```
Enter numbers one at a time. Enter '|' to end.
>> 12
>> 44
int 1: 12
int 2: 44

>> 98
>> 45
int 1: 98
int 2: 45

>> |
```

*Program terminates as expected.*

Here's a sample run of where things got strange:

```
Enter numbers one at a time. Enter '|' to end.
>> 54
>> |
int 1: 54
int 2: 0
```

*Program terminates*

As you can see, the code prints the values even when it never enters the `if-block`.
What happened? Why did the program print the two integers without getting into the block where the instruction to print exists? This happens every time when I enter the first number and enter '|' on second input prompt.

**UPDATE**
The following code works as expected:

```
int main() {                                                                    
    int in_int1;                                                                
    int in_int2;                                                                

    cout << endl << "Enter numbers one at a time. Enter '|' to end.";           
    cout << endl << ">> ";                                                      
    while (cin >> in_int1) { // CHANGE 1: the second condition was unnecessary 
        // because the condition fails when user enters non numeric
        // character anyway. Besides, I was comparing int with char.                                                    

        cout << ">> ";                                                          

        if (cin >> in_int2) { // CHANGE 2: similar logic applies here.                                                   
             cout << "int 1: " << in_int1 << endl;                              
             cout << "int 2: " << in_int2 << endl;                              
             cout << endl << ">> ";                                             
        } else {                                                                
            break;                                                              
        }                                                                       
    }                                                                           

    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Instead of entering '|' to terminate the program, I found out, with the help of commenters here, that entering 124 made my program behave as expected. I found out that comparing `int` with a `char` without explicit casting is generally a bad idea because the compiler doesn't warn about it and it sometimes produces unexpected result.

Comment: You are comparing `int` with `char`

Comment: @ArdentCoder Thanks. But it should not matter, because characters can be interpreted by compilers as integers. If this was the case than the first input inside while loop should not have worked either

Comment: Trying to read "|" as an integer fails. You can make it stop by entering 124. (Exercise: figure out why that is.)

Comment: With `cin >> in_int2` try to read an integer, but `|` is no integer.

Comment: @molbdnilo oh yes! when I enter 124 instead of |, the code works as expected! Thanks! I'll try to figure out why this happens.

Comment: @PPrasai Because that's the ASCII value of `'|'`. And your first run terminated because `cin` condition became `false` when it didn't read an integer

Comment: *"If this was the case than the first input inside while loop should not have worked either"* -- this is a premature conclusion. Your `while` loop checks an extra condition beyond what your `if` statement checks...

Comment: Thank you all for helping me figure this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This condition

```
if (in_int2 != '|')
```

can only be false when you entered the ASCII value for `|`. Naively you might expect that input `|` gets converted to the ASCII value and stored in `in_int2`. However, that does not happen. Instead `std::cin >> in_int2` fails if the user does not enter an integer.

If you want to check user input you could read the input as `std::string`, first check if it is valid, and only then convert it to an `int`. In general you should always check if input via `std::cin` succeeded by checking the state of the stream afterwards (as you correctly do for reading `in_int1`).

Note that also your first example terminates because of the first part of this condition:

```
 while (cin >> in_int1 && in_int1 != '|') {
```

When the user enters `|` then input fails and the conversion of `cin` to `bool` which `false` in this case. The first example does not terminate because of `&& in_int1 != '|'`. Again that part of the condition would only trigger if you entered a valid integer (ie first part of the condition evaluates to `true`) and that integer is the ASCII code for `|`.

Comment: Thanks. I get that now. But what hurts my brain is why does the second check prints the values but does not prompt for input?

Comment: @PPrasai I dont really understand, in your second example there are two user inputs. See edit, maybe that clarifies